# docker-compose: service "gateway" refers to undefined volume ${PWD}/config/gateway/gateway-configuration.ini: invalid compose project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

**My goal:** generate `docker-compose.yaml` from `docker-compose.yaml` and `docker-compose.override.yaml` and keep the variables as they are now = without interpolate

I've tried to run

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.override.yaml convert --no-interpolate > new-docker-compose.yaml
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.5"
services:

  redis-db:
    image: redislabs/rejson:2.0.11
    container_name: redis-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redis-storage-vol:/data
      - ${PWD}/config/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  runner:
    image: "${REPO}/runner/${RUNNER_CPU_IMAGE}:${RUNNER_CPU_TAG}"
    container_name: runner
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - data-storage-vol:/data
      - ${PWD}/config/runner/runner-configuration.ini:/configuration.ini:ro
      - "${PWD}/solutions/${ALGO}:/home/scripts/algorithmic_solutions_list.txt:ro"
    depends_on:
      - "redis-db"

  gateway:
    image: "${REPO}/gateway/gateway-server:${GATEWAY_TAG}"
    container_name: gateway
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - data-storage-vol:/data
      - ${PWD}/config/gateway/gateway-configuration.ini:/configuration.ini:ro
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - "redis-db"
      

volumes:
  data-storage-vol:
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: "tmpfs"
      o: "size=5g,uid=1000"

  redis-storage-vol:
    driver: local
```

`docker-compose.override.yaml`

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  runner:
    image: "${REPO}/runner/${RUNNER_GPU_IMAGE}:${RUNNER_GPU_TAG}"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities: [ GPU ]
```

What I've tried:

1. Run `docker compose convert` without flag `--no-interpolate`, it worked well but the variables was populated.
2. Run like the example - but got this error:
   `service "gateway" refers to undefined volume ${PWD}/config/gateway/gateway-configuration.ini: invalid compose project`

I want to keep using `docker compose` commands and not edit files after its created.

Comment: have you tried the flag `--no-consistency` in addition to `--no-interpolate`?

Comment: @flyx unknown flag: `--no-consistency`

Comment: You may need to update your docker, it [is certainly documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_convert/) as known flag.